# android marshmallow issue read a file from external storage

Tags: android, storage

i try to copy a sqlite database from file in my external storage this worked fine in android version ( 4 and 5 ) but doesn't work in android 6 (marshmallow) why ?? please help , As required, in its manifest, the following permissions are requested :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

here is my code :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2ActivityAdmin.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2ActivityAdmin.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2ActivityAdmin.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Main2ActivityAdmin.this, "permission erreur", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Main2ActivityAdmin.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
   private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {


    try {
        //InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File file = new File(sdcard, "sample.sqlite");
        InputStream  inputStream = null;
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("MainActivity","DB copied");
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to put the permission

> **Also change WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for Read permission**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (CheckPermission(MyActivity .this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // you have permission go ahead

            } else {
                // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
                RequestPermission(MyDevIDS.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            switch (permsRequestCode) {

                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // you have permission go ahead

                    } else {
                        // you do not have permission show toast.
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void RequestPermission(MyActivity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                        Permission)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                            new String[]{Permission},
                            Code);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean CheckPermission(MyActivity context, String Permission) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think i have no problem with the permission part , i think my problem is in this line : File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Comment: i edit my code , when i run my app in android 4 and 5 work fine but in android 6 i cannot copy the database from external storage even when im accpet the permission

Comment: if you add the permission than uninstall the app and install again And if also not work than see to go application manager and than your app and check the permission there is checked or not

Comment: i checked the permission in aplication manager and ( storage is activated ) , i dont andrstand why it work perfectly only in android 4 and 5

Comment: juste to inform , i placed the permission part into a previous activity and its work now